# position:fixed - and others elements

Tags: html, css, position

```
<div id="home">
    <div id="fix">aaa</div>
    <div id="text">bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb  </div>
</div>


#fix {
height: 200px;
width: 500px;
position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

#text {
background-color: green;
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
}
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/uK2RK/

Why this in example doesnt working margin? Now div #fix to cover div #text. I would like make margin. Cover should be only if page is in bottom etc

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking, please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work for you...

```
#fix {height: 200px; width: 500px; position: fixed; background-color: blue; top:0; left:0;}

#text {background-color: green;margin-top:200px;  width: 500px; height: 700px }
```

Comment: Thank you for marking it as answer. by the way one suggestion! the information provided by @Johnny is all important for your Question, you need to vote up his text.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of `position: fixed;` code. Browser can't do correct calculation with margin while it is fixed. Remove it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the position fixed

```
<div id="home">
    <div id="fix">aaa</div>
    <div id="text">bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb  </div>
</div>


#fix {
height: 200px;
width: 500px;

    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

#text {
background-color: green;
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
}
```