# "margin-top:auto" isn't working

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="home">
    <div id="fix">aaa<br />fff</div>
    <div id="text">bvvvbbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb  </div>
</div>
```

```
#fix {
    width: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#text {
    background-color: green;
    margin-top:auto;  
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
}
```

Why doesn't `margin-top` work in this example?

(In `div#fix`, the data is generated automatically with PHP.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uK2RK/9/

EDIT: Now div#fix cover to div#text. I can set margin-top, but i dont know how many lines this have, but this is generated automatically with PHP.

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you expect `margin-top:auto;` to actually *do*? Are you trying to [vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[css]+vertically+align) [align](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[css]+vertical+align&submit=search) the div?

Comment: Automatic vertical margins are a strange beast.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710777/positionfixed-and-others-elements

Answer (score 3):

It is working as it is supposed to (you didn't say how you *think* it is supposed to work).

As per section 10.6.3 of the [CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html) a `margin-top` with a value of `auto` on a block-level non-replaced element (such as a div) in normal flow (which #text is) with `overflow: visible` (the default) is treated as `margin-top: 0`.

The element is therefore positioned 0 pixels (unless there are other margins/paddings in play, which there are not) away from the bottom of the previous element in normal flow. Since the only previous element (#fix) is `position: fixed` and thus not in normal flow, there isn't such an element so #text gets placed 0 pixels away from the top of its container (#home). This position happens to be underneath #fix.

Comment: @RonCorazon — You can't. As it is `position: fixed` it is taken out of normal flow so margins of other elements don't touch it. You could fake it if you knew its height.

Comment: here, on stackoverflow is this possible - orange menu on top.

Comment: @RonCorazon — That menu (which isn't a menu, it is an alert message) is either of fixed height or isn't `position: fixed` (or both). I don't remember off the top of my head.